# How do I make text run top-to-bottom in CSS?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

Does anyone know how to make text align top-to-bottom in a div.

SO won't even let me demonstrate it . . . I just want the letters to stack on top of each other in a vertical line down the page like the stories of a building. Was hoping I didn't need to do it with an image.

Answer (score 45):

## Having your text run along vertical lines WITHOUT HACKS

#### `writing-mode`

[CSS `writing-mode` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) lets your text run vertically.

```css
.traditional-vertical-writing
{
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
```

```html
<p class="traditional-vertical-writing">
  This text runs vertically.<br>
  『只是』 （(but the thing is)），since Latin alphabets are not for vertical writing,
  not only the lines but each of the non-vertical-writing letters also gets rotated.<br>
  0123456789
</p>
```

---

#### `text-orientation`

If you don't want non-vertical-writing letters to rotate themselves in vertical lines, you may use [CSS `text-orientation` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation) as well.

```css
.vertical-writing
{
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: upright;
}
```

```html
<p class="vertical-writing">
  This text runs vertically.<br>
  『それに』 （(and in addition)）、now you don't have to turn your head 90 degrees clockwise
  to read these non-vertical-writing letters!<br>
  0123456789
</p>
```

---

And if you’re to do some *tate-chuu-yoko*<sup>[[1]](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B8%A6%E4%B8%AD%E6%A8%AA)[[2]](https://www.w3.org/TR/jlreq#handling_of_tatechuyoko)[[3]](https://www.w3.org/TR/klreq/#hangulromanmix)</sup> (縦中横； a bit of horizontal writing while writing vertically),

consider using [`text-combine-upright`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-combine-upright).

Comment: For _how to reverse the columns so that the first letter appears at the left_; I don’t know. Please comment it down if you happen to know the how.

Comment: Use `vertical-lr` instead of `vertical-rl` to have columns from **l**eft to **r**ight.

Comment: This is the only solution on the page that works for traditional Japanese texts. Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

To make the letters top-to-bottom while keeping their normal orientation, like this:

F

O

O

HTML:

```
<div class="toptobottom">letters</div>
```

CSS:

```
.toptobottom{
  width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

word-wrap allows words to be broken in the middle, so this will make the letters top-to-bottom. It's also really well supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/word-wrap

Comment: Thanks for this! I found that developing Japanese websites always bring us back to the basics.

Answer (score 5):

**Html:**

```
<div class="bottomtotop">Hello!</div>
```

**Css:**

```
.bottomtotop { transform:rotate(270deg); }
```

Comment: using transform property will let your text flow out from your container

Comment: Its changing the orientation of letters which isnt required in question.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I have used and it works for me:

CSS

```
.traditional-vertical-writing
 {
   writing-mode: vertical-rl;
   transform:rotate(180deg);
 }
```

HTML, Remember to put your text in

tag

```
<th rowspan="2" class="text-sm"><p class="traditional-vertical-writing">S/N</p></th>
```

RESULTS
[image]

Answer (score 0):

NJCodeMonkey's answer was close.

For me I had to use [`word-break`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_word-spacing.asp). It's a [little different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15137272/839501) from `word-wrap:break-word;`

So it would look like this.

### HTML:

```
<div class="VerticalText">LongTextWithNoSpaces</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.VerticalText
{
   width: 1px;
   word-break: break-all;
}
```

This worked for me in Firefox 24, IE 8 and IE 11.

Answer (score -2):

Depending on your font size, adjust accordingly:

```
<div style='width:12px'>a b c d</div>
```