# How to break lines when visiting sites from Android?

Tags: android, html

I have a site with many URL's, like this:

```
<div align="center">
...
<a href="foo.org/xyz">xyz!</a><br>
<a href="foo.org/xyz2">xyz2</a><br>
<a href="foo.org/xyz211">xyz211</a><br>
...
</div>
```

When I visit it from my phone/android2.1 it doesn't wrap the lines when they are too long to fit in the screen.

How should I write the mentioned URLs? What is the best "syntax/solution" to achieve long lines being wrapped when they don't fit the screen?

Comment: Do your lines contain whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

Try ['word-break: break-all' or 'word-wrap: break-word'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795109/what-is-the-difference-between-word-break-break-all-versus-word-wrap-break-w) in your CSS:

```
a {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```