# GWT - HTML widget - how not to wrap words

Tags: java, swing, gwt

I just faced an interesting thing concerning HTML widget. The thing is...

If **a word length is too long per line** then HTML widget becomes wider to have it all placed in

so my question is... is it possible to make HTML widget to **cut by pieces** long words not to getting wider itself?

Comparing to Swing, I mean the effect something like JTextArea does when word wrapping is off (see image)

[image]

---

**EDIT**

I tried to use css `word-break: break-all;` here is the code:

composite code:

```
public MyTestUI(){//constructor

 html.setStyleName("my-test");
}

public void setLongWord(String word)//method
{
  html.setHTML(word);
}
```

css

```
.my-test {
color:gray;
font-family:verdana;
white-space: normal;
word-break: break-all;
}
```

... the css works in Chrome but doesn't in FF :( How to make the word breaking the crossbrowser one ?

- GWT version 2.3

Any useful comment is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS property `word-wrap:break-word` as described in following link. This will work even if the HTML widget is having static height and width.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Comment: I tried break-word for HTML widget CSS html.setStyleName("my-style");  with following way  html.setHTML(too_long_word); but the word does not break :( What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to give your css code ? And also have a look at the parent css may not be getting overridden.

Comment: Try to use word-wrap:break-word, rather than word-break:break-all. This should definitely work. And try to analyze it with firebug or something else dependent on browser.

Answer (score 0):

Add a CSS style to your HTML widget to break long words:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp

EDIT:

I stay corrected: word-wrap is a better option. See more:

[What is the difference between "word-break: break-all" versus "word-wrap: break-word" in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795109/what-is-the-difference-between-word-break-break-all-versus-word-wrap-break)

Comment: Should HTML widget have static width then?

Comment: It should have width. It can be either set by you explicitly (in pixels or in percent), or it can derive its width from its parent element (i.e. 100% of the parent element). Otherwise the browser would not know at which width to start breaking words.

Comment: What if HTML widget will contain just ONE too long word? Will it be broken then?

Comment: Yes. It breaks all long words.

Comment: Does FF supports it? I tried but it seems like word-break: break-all works in Google Chrome but FF still doesn't break long word :( Is there the most optimal way?

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS property `word-break:normal;` or try `word-break:hyphenate;`

Comment: "Normal" is the default setting - it won't break any words.

Comment: I am not pretty sure what exactly the 'hyphenate' does? Give more details please

Comment: i Know normal wont break any words, i just gave him the options what all one can use with that property