# jQuery add newline if text is wider than div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, text

I add text to a div with the following jQuery code:

```
jQuery("div").text('some lorem ipsum');
```

The div has a maximum width of 400px set by css. If I enter a text which is longer than 400px and has no whitespace, the text will not get breaked down into a new line. Instead it overflows the div which I dont want. How can I solve it, that this text withouth whitespace is breaked down after 400px to a new line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in CSS with the `word-wrap` property:

```
div {
    word-wrap: break-word
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use css `word-break`   [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Uax3/)

```
div{
 word-break:break-all;
}
```

Comment: sry, the other guy was faster, so i marked it as right, but yours also a solution and i gave +1

Comment: @tester. just for your info: mine is faster than other if you see time difference. but his solution is better see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795109/what-is-the-difference-between-word-break-break-all-versus-word-wrap-break