# How to make div break line?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```css
.thing {
  width: 90%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 10px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="thing">
  aaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>
```

The problem is that when I add to much content, the text goes out of the div!

[image]

How to fix this using only CSS?

Comment: `padding: 10px solid #000;`........just to verify, you mean **border** right?

Answer (score 16):

```
.thing {
width: 90%;
height: 400px;
padding: 10px solid #000;
word-break:break-all;
}
```

use word-break

Comment: What is the difference between breakall and breakword?

Comment: break-all will move your word to next line if it does not fit into container width but break-word will break the word to make it fit into container width. see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795109/what-is-the-difference-between-word-break-break-all-versus-word-wrap-break

Answer (score 4):

this happen coze you are not adding space

just add a space some where between 'aa' **like this >** 'aaaaaa aaaaaa'
there is not word with **12 character**

but if you need this long word then use

```
word-break:break-all;
```