# Break line automatically when user input long text without adding white-space

Tags: php, css

I have a DIV container which used to display the text included by users. But, I have a problem when the users try to add long text without adding white-space(Ex: balalalalalalalala...) inside the text or that text is in Unicode character, so, it will display only one line overflow my DIV container.

I want that to add a break line automatically by itself. How to do that?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're down with CSS3 you may try the 'word-break' property.

To see a demo:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-break

Answer (score 0):

The CSS [word-wrap property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap) is compatible with older browsers (IE 5.5+, FF 3.5+, Chrome 1.0+, Safari 1.0+, Opera 10.5+).

CSS:

```
div { word-wrap: break-word; }
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XtqsE/).

That should work if `white-space` doesn't, otherwise just use `white-space: pre-wrap`.

Comment: Thank you so much !! This helps me a lot, but can you please explain me what the difference between "word-break:break-all" and "word-wrap: break-word" is?? I just want to know that. :) thanks again. ;)

Comment: @VyEm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795109/what-is-the-difference-between-word-break-break-all-versus-word-wrap-break