# How to align DIV contains String with no Spaces

Tags: jquery, css, string, html, alignment

I have a Dynamic **String with no Spaces**

```
i.e: 12345678912345678912345634589 // This is a dynamic content from php.
```

And i have a **DIV** with **200px width**
So this String is going out of the **DIV** if there is **no spaces** in the String.
How can i fix it? I want this string started from **New Line** when it reaches the width limit of 200px.

**I have also made a JsFiddle DEMO :**

http://jsfiddle.net/ACF7N/6/

Comment: Use Word-wrap:break-word css property

Answer (score 4):

```
div {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp

Comment: In case you wanted to know which browsers support it: http://caniuse.com/word-break

Comment: If you are wondering what the difference between `word-break` and `word-wrap` is (both work), the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795109/what-is-the-difference-between-word-break-break-all-versus-word-wrap-break

Comment: @technophobia I wasn't aware that browser support was being dropped. Use the answer that nnnnnn gave instead.

Comment: You misunderstood, I was just sharing a resource to help him identify which browser support the feature - that is all! :)

Comment: Absolutely - but as less browsers support word-break (and that looks like it will get worse as time goes on) the OP would be much better off using word-wrap. I thought both were pretty much globally implemented, but clearly that's not the case. Bloody Opera =]

Answer (score 2):

Add this CSS:

```
word-wrap : break-word;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ACF7N/7/

Answer (score 0):

```
#description
{
    border:1px solid #BBBBBB;
    width:200px; 
    word-wrap: break-word; //Add this
}
```

Alternatively, You can also use

```
overflow-wrap:break-word;
```

From the specification, http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#overflow-wrap, 
‘word-wrap’ as an alternate name for the ‘overflow-wrap’

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the content to be on one line still, you can use something similar to this to get that:

```
#description
{
    border:1px solid #BBBBBB;
    width:200px;
    overflow:hidden; //add this
    text-overflow:ellipsis;  //and this
}
```

If you're not worried about it going onto a new line, one of the other answers will help you :)