# make html content go on next line automatically

Tags: html, css

I am creating a chat application and in that I am dynamically populating the messages in a div

```
$('#conversation').append('<div class="message"><span><b>'+username+': </b>' + data + '</span></div>');
```

But the problem is if the message is too long, it is not going on the next line. I tried with

```
white-space:normal;
```

but no luck yet.
Here is the dummy [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ajey/dSu47/)

Answer (score 2):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dSu47/1/)

```
.message {
    white-space: normal;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the css style you want to add is

```
word-wrap:break-word
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should to edit your code with this:

```
span{display:inline-block;}
```

Comment: OP posted a fiddle with his 6 year old question. If you tried it you should have seen that this does not work. you might want to look at how to create code examples in an answer so you can check out how the code behaves without leaving stackoverflow. The correct answer has been given here but OP didn't check back in to accept an answer

Answer (score 0):

just use  `word-break: break-word;`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/n9JSL/)

```
 .message {
        white-space:normal;
        word-break: break-word;
    }
```

refer
http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/

Tips:

> It is also often used in conjunction with the hyphens property so that
>   when breaks occur a hypen is inserted, as per the standard in books.
>
> ```
>      -ms-word-break: break-all;
>      word-break: break-all;
>
>      // Non standard for webkit
>      word-break: break-word;
>
> -webkit-hyphens: auto;
>    -moz-hyphens: auto;
>         hyphens: auto;
> ```

Comment: and what is the difference between word-break and word-wrap ? Both seem to give the same result

Comment: @Ajey: please refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795109/what-is-the-difference-between-word-break-break-all-versus-word-wrap-break