# How to make fixed width td If I enter data without space

Tags: html, html-table

I have a Fixed size table and I have to show the data in a td. The Issue is If I enter the Data with spaces then UI is appearing Perfect because in td data adjust in new line but if i entered 20 characters without space then my UI got disturbed. Any help will be appreciated. I have tried so many option but no one can help, like:-

```
 <td width="200"></td>
```

and

```
 table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100px;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `word-break:break-all;` on your `td` example here - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k5NtB/)

*Browser support for word-break - [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/word-break)*

Answer (score 1):

You should give "word-wrap: break-word;" a try.

Comment: For completeness: [word-break:break-all; vs. word-wrap: break-word;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795109/what-is-the-difference-between-word-break-break-all-versus-word-wrap-break)