# mix of word-wrap and word-break css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have read about word-wrap and word-break [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795109/what-is-the-difference-between-word-break-break-all-versus-word-wrap-break)
I wonder how about mix of them, such as:

```
<span style="width: 70px; word-wrap:break-word; word-break: break-all;"> your text hereeeeeeeeeeeee </span>
```

maybe display as:

```
your text
hereeeeeee
eeeee
```

first wrap word with whitespace, then if length of 'hereeeeeeeeeeeee' more than 70px then break-all ?
but it seem to be always use break-all.

there is any way too make it work :-? css or jQuery

Comment: [You mean like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/cuplizian/hr3NU/)

Comment: @IanMustafa hmmm, you right, but it still not work if using width % (in my case: inside table td)