# Overflowing input text

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qox0yxb4/

I am using `type()` to create a typewriter affect (each character is printed on the screen with a delay in between). I use `addTextToScreen(textForScreen)` to add text to the queue which is then added to the screen through `type()`. When I call `addTextToScreen()` from within the JavaScript, the text seems to be formatted as it does NOT overflow on the x-axis, however when I accept input from an HTML `<input>` tag (`printText()`), the text overflows on the x-axis.

Here are the JavaScript methods:

```
var i = 0,
isTag=false,
text;

var typeTime = 45;

function type() {
    if (text === textOnScreen){
      setTimeout(function(){type();}, typeTime);
      return;
    }
    text = textOnScreen.slice(0, i+1);
    i++;
    document.getElementById('paraText').innerHTML = text;

    var char = text.slice(-1);
    console.log(char);
    if( char === '<' ) isTag = true;
    if( char === '>' ) isTag = false;

    if (isTag) return type();

    setTimeout(function(){type();}, typeTime);
}

function addTextToScreen(textForScreen){
    textOnScreen = textOnScreen + textForScreen;
}

type();

function printText(event) {
   if(event.keyCode == 13){
        printText = document.getElementById("inputText").value.toString();
        addTextToScreen("<br>" + printText.toString());
        x = document.getElementById("inputText");
        x.value = "";
   }
}
```

I also noticed that whenever I paste text into the input box (the text can be from anywhere) it seems to be formatted, and it does NOT overflow.

Comment: Could you post enough code for us to reproduce the problem? We don't know what `text` and `typeTime` are, and we don't have your HTML code. Posting a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demo would be best.

Comment: @blex typeTime is irrelevant to my question, however I have added it in now.

Comment: I would recommend truncating the line...that's the easiest solution to your problem. You'll lose data but it solves your issue.

Comment: @blex I have now also added a jsfiddle demo, hope this helps :)

Comment: It's not overflowing for me.  Perhaps your input is a long string with no spaces (e.g., `eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee`), which would not wrap.  However, you'll notice that that will happen whether you do it programmatically (like your example text) or through the UI.  So, as a test, paste you current test text (`HELLO there, as you can see...`) in the UI and hit enter, and you'll see it works as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this css property to `#paraText`:

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo

[Josh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2145980/josh-burgess) suggested using `break-all`, [here is the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795109/what-is-the-difference-between-word-break-break-all-versus-word-wrap-break).

Answer (score 1):

The magic CSS rule you're missing is `word-break: break-all;`.  Add that, and it works just like you'd expect.

## [Proof](http://jsfiddle.net/qox0yxb4/3/)