# Proper wordbreaking with CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Now, I am working on project where users can create their own time lines. Each timeline has events. There's a problem with event title.

User can create event with very long title. For example:

```
`12312312312312312312312313211233123213133gsfsfsfsdfserwerwerwerwesdfsdf`
```

or

```
День победы русской эскадры под командованием Ф.Ф. Ушакова над турецкой эскадрой у мыса Тендра
```

Title displays with h3 and word-break:break-all

Examples:
[image]
[image]

I suppose that for the first example it works well enough. But the second example violates the rules of hyphenation.

Is there any plugin that will help? Or maybe proper CSS rules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use in css. there is a difference between to what time to use word-break and word wrap. For more information see the docs and Stackoverflow link

```
 h3 {
   word-wrap: break-word;
 }
```

Docs : [**W3school**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-wrap)

[**Stackoverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795109/what-is-the-difference-between-word-break-break-all-versus-word-wrap-break)

Comment: Please, don't use w3school as reference: http://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/50ec111ed13434dd5b002d4e

Also: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Its just forum i didn't mind it. W3school is basic to learn all tutorials for begineers.

Comment: @A.Rama, please explain in your own words why shouldn't we refer to W3C.

Comment: @JqueryKing sorry, my bad. Your answer works. There was a problem with parent's div width