# Displaying Javascript variable into multiline in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, ember.js

I am getting dynamic variable from webservice. I want to add the empty space or breaktag tag in the javascript variable.

For eg:

let myVal = "myname 123456789 NZD".

when displaying in the UI I want to display the names like below in a single div

```
myname 
123456789
NZD
```

The variable name all are dynamic. I am using word-wrap: break-word.

But few text cut of eg:

```
firstname last
name 123456789.
```

How to achieve like below :

```
myname 
123456789 
NZD
```

I am using below css:

```
div{
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 46%;
    min-height: 22px;
    height: auto;
    font-family: "Montserrat-SemiBold";
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.47;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #000000;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding line breaks like this: `myVal.split(' ').join('<br>')`?

Comment: @Romen - That will fail if `myVal` contains `<` or `&`.

Comment: maybe this answer will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33300106/break-line-on-white-space-between-words

Comment: Nope. I will check and will let you know. Thanks

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, If by "fail" you mean not display properly due to malformed HTML, well that's going to happen before calling the `split` and `join` if `myVal` has it in the first place.

Comment: @Romen - Yup, but we don't want to perpetuate it.

Comment: it actually wont work but will not fail with a `<` if hes actually using ember, because ember does the escaping so that every string will be displayed as text node, not HTML. You could explicit opt out with safe string tho.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="one-word-each-line" style="
    width: min-intrinsic;
    width: -webkit-min-content;
    width: -moz-min-content;
    width: min-content;
    display: table-caption;
    display: -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: min-content;
">myname 123456789 NZD</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're using ember I could use a computed property in combination with a `{{#each}}` loop producing `<br>` tags:

so a computed property in your component or controller like this:

```
splittedValue: computed('myVal', function() {
  return this.myVal.split(' ');
}),
```

and then this in the template:

```
<div>
  {{#each this.splittedValue as |line|}}
    {{line}}<br>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this out. Dynamic and reusable.

```js
 function createWrapper(value) {
  const wrapper = document.createElement("div");
  wrapper.classList.add("wrapper");
  value.split(" ")
       .forEach(v => {
        const span = document.createElement("span");
        span.innerText = v;
        wrapper.appendChild(span);
        });
  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(wrapper);
 }
 createWrapper("Alex 575 ASD");
 createWrapper("Siya 666 ABC");
 createWrapper("Jack 090 XYZ");
```

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }
```

```html
 <div id="container">
 </div>
```