# How to line break words in span

Tags: html, css

I have span inside text like this

```
<span class='btntext'>New Item</span>
```

How to show words like

```
New
Item
```

I tried `white-space:nowrap;` and `word-break:break-all;` but not worked...

```
.btntext{
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just use `html`? => `<span class='btntext'>New <br> Item</span>`

Comment: "I have span inside text like this". Did you mean you have text inside a span

Comment: @j08691 yes let me fix

Comment: restrict the width of the span and apply display:inline-block to it

Comment: Have you seen [this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33300106/break-line-on-white-space-between-words)

Comment: @johannchopin The `<br>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: @johannchopin dirty way pls...

Comment: @EvanBechtol no

Comment: @Rob Of course sorry I'm too used to `jsx`

Comment: You need to limit the size of the span and set the `word-break`, or `letter-spacing` property on the span itself. Otherwise the text has no way of wrapping like you want, and will almost certainly have different behavior on different viewport sizes.

Comment: @EvanBechtol can you write an example

Comment: The example is in the answer that I linked to you. Or the one at the top of your question.