# Change the font size after break line on white space between words

Tags: html, css, whitespace, font-size

I found the solution how to break line on white space between words in this solution which is very helpful:
[Break line on white space between words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33300106/break-line-on-white-space-between-words)

```
.test{
text-align:center;
}
h1{
word-spacing:9999px;
}

<div class="test">
<h1>split this</h1>
</div>
```

However, can do I change the font size in css after break the line???  example below:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZV1j.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, target the first line to make its size bigger:

```css
.test {
  text-align: center;
  font-size:8px;
}
.test:first-line {
  font-size:40px;
}

h1 {
  word-spacing: 9999px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <h1>split this</h1>
</div>
```

And here is another trick to create line break with `word-spacing`

```css
.test {
  width:min-content;
  margin:auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:8px;
}
.test:first-line {
  font-size:40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <h1>split this</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above. You can create span tags and use the pseudo class nth-child to stylise the desired span.

```
<div class="test">
  <span class="text">split</span>
  <span class="text">this</span>
</div>

.test {
  text-align: center;
}
.test .text {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
.test .text:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 3rem
}
```