# Different line-height value for 1 line or more than 1 line

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

previously I have ask the question about "Change the font size after break line on white space between words", I got the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62807105/change-the-font-size-after-break-line-on-white-space-between-words/62810464#62810464)

However, I have setup line-height in css for this, I want to know, if only one single line, my line-height value is 30px, whereas, if I have more than 1 line, than the value for line-height will be 10px, it depends sometimes it will have 1 line only, sometimes it might have 2 lines. Please see my example below for your better understanding, can I do so in css?

[image]

Comment: you can display your example here, pls?

Comment: you are tackling the problem the wrong way. keep the line-height:10px and center the content instead