# HTML: How to force a long text to break

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know that there are related questions already posted on this site, but i still cannot find the right code for this.. I already searched the net and I found some right answers regarding this question. This the code I used to force break a line

```
/* break long text without spaces */         
word-break: break-all;       
word-break: break-word;          
hyphens: auto;
```

im ok with the long text, problem has been solved with the above code..
but for normal texts: (tho the word is not that long, it's still been splitted)

```
If Mail notifications is check 
ed, you will receive notificat 
ions about any event that occu 
rs on the projects you belong to
```

**

here is the link of what I've started
http://jsfiddle.net/y4Mdy/1802/

sorry if my explanation is too vague.
thanks in advance to all who will reply :)

Comment: What is the behavior you're looking for?
When I open your jsfiddle, and adjust the width, the words in the text don't get split (like it's supposed to, right?)

Comment: I don't want short words to get splitted, instead it will just go to the next line

Comment: The demo you provided does not show the issue - http://puu.sh/n9VAV/8bd871687f.png

Comment: based on my sample above..instead of creating a new line when reaching the  word **checked** ... it gets split , making it a two words(check, ed)

Comment: CSS can't detect long or short words...it can only do what you tell it to. You'll have to pick the behaviour you require.

Comment: might be useful to check `text-overflow` and [this technique](http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y4Mdy/1809/

If I got you right, you wanted to break all the spaces and display them later? If so I have a way, hoping this is what you actually asked for:

```
<body>

  <div id="form" class="message-box">
    <div class="message-containter">
        If Mail notifications is checked, you will receive notifications about any event that occurs on the projects you belong to (issue added or edited, new document,...).
      </div>


      <div class="message right">
        dfsfsfsfsfddfsfsfsfsfdsfsdfsdfdfsfsfsfsfdsfsdfsdfdfsfsfsfsfdsfsdfsdfdfsfsfsfsfdsfsdfsdfdfsfsfsfsfdsfsdfsdfdfsfsfsfsfdsfsdfsdfdfsfsfsfsfdsfsdfsdfdfsfsfsfsfdsfsdfsdfdfsfsfsfsfdsfsdfsdfdfsfsfsfsfdsfsdfsdfdfsfsfsfsfdsfsdfsdfdfsfsfsfsfdsfsdfsdfdfsfsfsfsfdsfsdfsdfdfsfsfsfsfdsfsdfsdfdfsfsfsfsfdsfsdfsdfdfsfsfsfsfdsfsdfsdfdfsfsfsfsfdsfsdfsdfdfsfsfsfsfdsfsdfsdfdfsfsfsfsfdsfsdfsdfdfsfsfsfsfdsfsdfsdfdfsfsfsfsfdsfsdfsdfdfsfsfsfsfdsfsdfsdfdfsfsfsfsfdsfsdfs
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

 <br> <div id ="newdiv"></div>

</body>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var getclass = document.getElementsByClassName("message-containter")[0].innerHTML;
var result = text(getclass);

function text(text){

    var arr = text.split("");

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ //loop through the array
        if (arr[i] !== " "){ //if there isn't a space
            var current = document.getElementById('newdiv');
            current.innerHTML = current.innerHTML + arr[i]; //write the letter
        }
    }


}

console.log(document.getElementById('newdiv').innerHTML); //the entire string

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is because of `word-break: break-all;` as it breaks words even if it  continuous and extends the width. so you can simply use  `overflow-wrap: break-word`.

For more on this read [What is the difference between "word-break: break-all" versus "word-wrap: break-word" in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795109/what-is-the-difference-between-word-break-break-all-versus-word-wrap-break)

Comment: That's perfect!