# CSS: <tbody> width is wider than <table> width. Text is not wrapping

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <tbody class="tBody">
      <tr>
        <td>Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</td>
        <td>World</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.container {width: 100%;}
.table {display:block;}
.tBody {max-width: inherit;}
```

My problem is that the total width is defined by a dragbar, so the widths of all the elements must me dynamic. I want the text inside the `<td>` element to be able to wrap itself dynamically. So far, the `<div>`'s width changes its value according to the position of the dragbar. To make it have the `<div>`'s width, I set the `<table>` CSS to `display:block`. The rest of the elements in the table, `<tbody>`, `<tr>`, `<td>`, set their width to the widest element in the table, which in this case is the text 'Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo'. So right now, if I move the dragbar to try to make the table smaller, the `div` will change its width but the table elements' width will remain the same. Text won't wrap either.

How to make the width of a table (and its children) be set by a dragbar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add this line to your CSS :

```
td {word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-all;}
```

A demo :

```css
.container {width: 100%;}
.table {display:block;}
.tBody {max-width: inherit;}
td {word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-all;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <tbody class="tBody">
      <tr>
        <td>Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</td>
        <td>World</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/f1voj6rc/).

Comment: This worked, just after I **double checked there were no** `white-space: nowrap;` rules messing with the table elements.

Comment: Also, I had to read a little about the difference between `word-wrap` and and `word-break`, [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795109/what-is-the-difference-between-word-break-break-all-versus-word-wrap-break 
It seems to me there is no need to use them in the same element/class.

Comment: @RaquelRedondo : Browser support for [`word-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap) is generally a bit better than for [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break), but [not really for `<td>` elements](http://maxdesign.com.au/jobs/sample-wordwrap/index.htm). I always combine them by default to get the behavior you want on the greatest number of browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

You can use [word-wrap](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp) and [word-break](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp) properties like:

```
.table {
  display:block;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  word-break: break-all;     
}
```