# Browser compatibility for "overflow-wrap:break-word"

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser

I added `overflow-wrap: break-word` to my css file to support long string.

Does anyone know how to enhance browser compatibility?

Comment: `word-wrap` - [take a look](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp)

Comment: Correct, use "word-wrap". See: http://caniuse.com/#search=overflow-w

Comment: have a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795109/what-is-the-difference-between-word-break-break-all-versus-word-wrap-break/15137272#15137272

Comment: @haeminish What is the reason for linking to that other SO question?

Comment: someone said that word-wrap is moved to overflow-wrap. Seems like I can have both in my css.

Answer (score 1):

The older name which you can use for backwards compatibility is `word-wrap`. Be sure to put the older property first, like so:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

- http://caniuse.com/#search=overflow-w
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

Comment: So putting word-wrap before overflow-wrap will take care of backwards compatibility while the other is for newer browsers?

Comment: It should, yes. Any browser that recognizes both should have the same behavior for both. Any browser that only uses the older one will just ignore the newer one.

Comment: in the first link `http://caniuse.com/#search=overflow-w` seems like IE only partially support word-wrap. In fact, word-wrap and overflow-wrap are supported exactly the same.

Comment: Just to clarify, firefox 48 doesn't recognize `overflow-wrap`. I guess the yellow ones are for `word-wrap`