# Why are my elements overflowing and creating a scroll bar?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Sections are block elements by default. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

The css I have is simple and I'm adding an styling to the sections parent which is the only div.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 0 20%;
}

li {
  margin: 5px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  example
</h1>
<ul>
  <li>rfg</li>
  <li>ert</li>
  <li>sghgh</li>
  <li>sgh</li>
</ul>

<div>
  <section>
    fnflsnljnlfjnljsljrljnlkfjgnljritljfnglejrtldlfkgjvncmdkfjghtredkfvncxmcnvhfjdkjsklwoeiruthgnbhtruejfhvbcnmznxcbfgrehjwkweuryturioepoifugvnvbfhncjdgturieowwoeirujdnbfgrgvtbnhjbgkklfodisjzhxvsfaghweyrghjcvhfjdiwowpowieurytgfhjdcnncfhdnfhfdfhgffghfnfhn
  </section>
  <section>
    fnflsnljnlfjnljsljrljnlkfjgnljritljfnglejrtldlfkgjvncmdkfjghtredkfvncxmcnvhfjdkjsklwoeiruthgnbhtruejfhvbcnmznxcbfgrehjwkweuryturioepoifugvnvbfhncjdgturieowwoeirujdnbfgrgvtbnhjbgkklfodisjzhxvsfaghweyrghjcvhfjdiwowpowieurytgfhjdcnncfhdnfhfdfhgffghfnfhn
  </section>
  <section>
    fnflsnljnlfjnljsljrljnlkfjgnljritljfnglejrtldlfkgjvncmdkfjghtredkfvncxmcnvhfjdkjsklwoeiruthgnbhtruejfhvbcnmznxcbfgrehjwkweuryturioepoifugvnvbfhncjdgturieowwoeirujdnbfgrgvtbnhjbgkklfodisjzhxvsfaghweyrghjcvhfjdiwowpowieurytgfhjdcnncfhdnfhfdfhgffghfnfhn
  </section>
  <section>
    fnflsnljnlfjnljsljrljnlkfjgnljritljfnglejrtldlfkgjvncmdkfjghtredkfvncxmcnvhfjdkjsklwoeiruthgnbhtruejfhvbcnmznxcbfgrehjwkweuryturioepoifugvnvbfhncjdgturieowwoeirujdnbfgrgvtbnhjbgkklfodisjzhxvsfaghweyrghjcvhfjdiwowpowieurytgfhjdcnncfhdnfhfdfhgffghfnfhn
  </section>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9ewcexpz/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `long text` of `continuous word` that's why it behaving as inline, so add `word-break:break-all` or add `spacing` as below,

> Note - The section element is not a generic container element. When an
>   element is needed only for styling purposes or as a convenience for
>   scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead. A
>   general rule is that the section element is appropriate only if the
>   element's contents would be listed explicitly in the document's
>   outline.

```css
h1{
  text-align: center;
}
ul{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin:0 20%;
}
li{
  margin: 5px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>
example
</h1>
<ul>
  <li>rfg</li>
  <li>ert</li>
  <li>sghgh</li>
  <li>sgh</li>
</ul>

<div>
  <section>
 fnflsnljnlfjnljsljrljn lkfjgnljritljfnglejrtldl fkgjvncmdkfjghtre dkfvnc x mcnvhfj dkjsklwoeir uthgnbhtr uejfhvbc nmznxcbfgre hjwkweurytur ioepoifugvnvbfhnc jdgturieowwoe irujdnbfgrgvtbnhj bgkklfodisjzhxvsf aghweyrghjcvhfjdi wowpowieurytgf hjdcnncf hdnfhfdf hgffghfnfhn
 </section>
 
 <section>
 fnflsnljnlfjnljsljrljn lkfjgnljritljfnglejrtldl fkgjvncmdkfjghtre dkfvnc x mcnvhfj dkjsklwoeir uthgnbhtr uejfhvbc nmznxcbfgre hjwkweurytur ioepoifugvnvbfhnc jdgturieowwoe irujdnbfgrgvtbnhj bgkklfodisjzhxvsf aghweyrghjcvhfjdi wowpowieurytgf hjdcnncf hdnfhfdf hgffghfnfhn
  </section>
  <section>
 fnflsnljnlfjnljsljrljn lkfjgnljritljfnglejrtldl fkgjvncmdkfjghtre dkfvnc x mcnvhfj dkjsklwoeir uthgnbhtr uejfhvbc nmznxcbfgre hjwkweurytur ioepoifugvnvbfhnc jdgturieowwoe irujdnbfgrgvtbnhj bgkklfodisjzhxvsf aghweyrghjcvhfjdi wowpowieurytgf hjdcnncf hdnfhfdf hgffghfnfhn
 </section>  
 <section>
 fnflsnljnlfjnljsljrljn lkfjgnljritljfnglejrtldl fkgjvncmdkfjghtre dkfvnc x mcnvhfj dkjsklwoeir uthgnbhtr uejfhvbc nmznxcbfgre hjwkweurytur ioepoifugvnvbfhnc jdgturieowwoe irujdnbfgrgvtbnhj bgkklfodisjzhxvsf aghweyrghjcvhfjdi wowpowieurytgf hjdcnncf hdnfhfdf hgffghfnfhn
  </section>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the English language, lines can normally wrap when there is a space between letters. (The rules for line breaks vary among languages.)

But in your `section` element there is no whitespace, so the lines don't wrap.

Add this to your CSS:

```
section { word-break: break-all }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9ewcexpz/19/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Comment: Maybe `word-wrap: break-word` would be a better choice here. I think this will break regular words as well (which is usually not the desired result)

Comment: @Danield, thanks for the feedback. `word-wrap` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap?v=example), I believe (it's now `overflow-wrap`). Regardless, your point may be valid. For anybody interested, here's a good discussion of the difference between the two: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1795109/3597276

Comment: You're right that `word-wrap` is deprecated, but the problem is that `overflow-wrap` isn't fully supported - http://caniuse.com/#feat=wordwrap - so that's why I'm still sticking with word-wrap :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `section`'s text is just one whole word, so it overflows. It has nothing to do with the flexbox. Just add

```
section {word-wrap: break-word;}
```