# Flexbox item multiline text overflow

Tags: css, flexbox

I have flex item with very long string inside, and I want it to be wraped. But it doesn't work.

I set `flex 1 1 500px`, for instance (`flex-basis = 500px`) and it should wrap the string with `word wrap: break-word`

But it doesn't, and only if I set `width=500px`, it starts to work, so the question is why `flex-basis 500px` doesn't work and width works?

HTML:

```
<div class="map-detail-wrapper">
    <div class="ad-detail-text">
        <span>{{ad.text}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.map-detail-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.ad-detail-text {
    flex: 1 1 0%;
    width: 500px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 20px;
    border: black;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In your case you are allowing the item to shrink giving it `flex: 1 1 500px` which is short for:

```
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-basis: 500px;
```

since the content is less the `500px` width and the item is allowed to shrink, it will. To fix that you can set `flex: 0 0 500px`

In most cases `flex-basis` is equivalent to `width`, you can read more about the differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34355447/714143)

For the difference between `word-break: break-all` and `word-wrap: break-word` you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795109/what-is-the-difference-between-word-break-break-all-versus-word-wrap-break/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work. You can check it in this example. https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FFPNFOV52YNW

Comment: in that case you are telling each item to be `100%` the width of the parent

Answer (score 2):

Finnally found workaround. You can see it there https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FFPNFOV52YNW

It enough to add 
"word-break: break-all;" 
and it starting to work even without "width" only with "flex-basis".

But i still wondering why 
"word-wrap: break-word" works only with "width", 
and to make word wrap only with flex-basis it requires "word-break: break-all;"