# Break within word *if required* in a HTML table

Tags: css, html-table

I have a fixed-width table (with variable-width columns). If a user enters long entries without spaces, the table expands horizontally and the layout breaks.

I can use `word-break: break-all` to fix this, but this breaks lines in the middle of words, *even if* there is a suitable space. Supposedly, this can be fixed with `word-wrap: break-word`, but, unfortunately, [it doesn't work as expected in tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19282567/87698).

Here is an example with `word-break: break-all` and `word-wrap: break-word`:

```html
<table style="width: 200px; border: 1px solid black;">
    <tr>
        <td style="word-wrap: break-word">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
            incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

            aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        </td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table style="width: 200px; border: 1px solid black;">
    <tr>
        <td style="word-break: break-all">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
            incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

            aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        </td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and here is what I want it to look like:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,       |
| consectetur adipiscing elit,      |
| sed do eiusmod tempor             |
| incididunt ut labore et           |
| dolore magna aliqua.         1234 |
| aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa      |
| aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa      |
| aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa            |
+-----------------------------------+
```

i.e. linebreaks within words *if and only if* there is no possibility to naturally break it.

I know that `table-layout: fixed` would make the table work with `word-wrap: break-word`, but then the columns would no longer be variable-width. I want to keep using a `table` instead of `div`s, since the data itself is tabular in nature.

Is there a way to do that in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Not CSS, but you can use [`<wbr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr) to designate where to break a word (only if necessary).

```html
<table style="width: 200px; border: 1px solid black;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
            incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

            aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<wbr>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<wbr>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        </td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How would I know where to place these within user-entered text?

Comment: I guess that would be where you'd have to determine it beforehand, which isn't too nice for responsiveness.

Comment: @Heinzi actually, a much easier way would be to use `max-width`