# css wordwrap, how does it work?

Tags: html, css

i've got a table that need to look not ugly on a phone but on my phone the first text doesnt get split by default but the text with `-` will

is there a way to split a Text that isnt cut off by `space` or `-` with CSS?

// WHAT I MEAN

```css
.small{
  max-width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="small">
<span>This Text gets split</span>
</div>
<div style="min-height: 15px"></div>
<div class="small">
<span>ThisWontGetSpilt</span>
</div>
<div style="min-height: 15px"></div>
<div class="small">
<span>This-Will-Get-Split-As-Well</span>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795109/what-is-the-difference-between-word-break-break-all-versus-word-wrap-break/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `overflow-wrap: break-word;`

```css
.small{
  max-width: 50px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="small">
<span>This Text gets split</span>
</div>
<div style="min-height: 15px"></div>
<div class="small">
<span>ThisWontGetSpilt</span>
</div>
<div style="min-height: 15px"></div>
<div class="small">
<span>This-Will-Get-Split-As-Well</span>
</div>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `word-break: break-all;` to achieve this effect.

```css
.container {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 100px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>This is too long for the container, but get's broken properly with the word-break css property.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sure, but in OPs example that breaks after each letter so not the ideal one.

Comment: I agree, should have paid more attention to the original question. For anyone reading this after the fact, Serge Inácio has a better answer since it maintains word readability.