# Is it possible to make a sticky table header with rotated header cells?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The table below contains a sticky table header, however I would like a few of the table header cells to be rotated. The issue here is that currently these table header cells (`<th>` elements) will be appearing outside of the screen or table header itself (`<thead>` element).

Is it possible to make a sticky table header with rotated header cells?

Working table with sticky header (optional sample code):

```css
.example {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #afc8f0;
  text-align: center;
}

.sticky-table thead tr th {
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">

      <div class="example">
        ... Sample content ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Sample content ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Sample content ...
      </div>

      <!-- ...
        Some other elements
        .. -->

      <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm sticky-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Handle</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <div class="example">
        ... Sample content ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Sample content ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Sample content ...
      </div>

      <!-- ...
        Some other elements
        .. -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/femadcjb/)

Broken table with sticky header (this piece of code contains what I am trying to do):

Added `style="transform: rotate(-90deg); text-align: center;"` to a `<th>` element.

```css
.example {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #afc8f0;
  text-align: center;
}

.sticky-table thead tr th {
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">

      <div class="example">
        ... Sample content ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Sample content ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Sample content ...
      </div>

      <!-- ...
        Some other elements
        .. -->

      <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm sticky-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col" style="transform: rotate(-90deg); text-align: center;">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Handle</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <div class="example">
        ... Sample content ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Sample content ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Sample content ...
      </div>

      <!-- ...
        Some other elements
        .. -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/94da8vt1/)

(To replicate the problem, please try to scroll down and see the result. The table header will not be entirely visible and when assigning a `background-color` to all the `<th>` elements, it will appear outside of the `<thead>` as well).

The reason for the rotation is because I want to save some space in width of the table by changing table header orientation.

Am I required to rather write some JavaScript for this kind of behaviour or will plain CSS be able to solve this issue too?

Answer (score 1):

You could instead of rotating the text as a block, have the text written in a top-to-bottom instead of left-to-right orientation:

(Thanks to [Константин Ван](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53576895/204723) for the inspiration)

```css
.example {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #afc8f0;
  text-align: center;
}

.sticky-table thead tr th {
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.sticky-table thead tr th.vertical {
  -webkit-text-orientation: upright;
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: upright;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-align: center;
}

.sticky-table thead tr th.vertical span.chromeFix
{
  text-orientation: upright;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">

      <div class="example">
        ... Sample content ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Sample content ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Sample content ...
      </div>

      <!-- ...
        Some other elements
        .. -->

      <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm sticky-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col" class="vertical"><span class="chromeFix">First</span></th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Handle</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <div class="example">
        ... Sample content ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Sample content ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Sample content ...
      </div>

      <!-- ...
        Some other elements
        .. -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Notes

Having checked in Edge, this might not be the best solution, as it's not compatible with all browsers.

Thanks to [Turnip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56885862/is-it-possible-to-make-a-sticky-table-header-with-rotated-header-cells/56886091?noredirect=1#comment100321165_56886091) for pointing out that this only works in Chrome if you wrap the text in a `span` or some such thing.

Comment: Am I missing something? All this does is center `First`.

Comment: This makes "first" be displayed with the letters underneath eachother. I can't show you in a comment, but it's distinct to the OP's "broken" version.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts this works in Firefox, other browsers seem to have difficulty.

Comment: This doesn't work in the latest version of Chrome unless the text is wrapped in another element (`<span>`, `<p>` etc.)

Comment: Yeah I might need something that is more compatible.

Comment: @Turnip weirdly mdn's [page on writing-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) lists chrome as supporting it with a prefix, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: If you wrap the word "First" in a `div` and apply the styles to the `div` rather than the `th` it works. @MattEllen - Example: https://jsfiddle.net/80fz6rem/

Comment: This kind of looks like something I could use, though I am still curious if there would be a possible solution for just plain rotation as well.