# How do I overflow text to the left in a table?

Tags: html, css

I have a table with fixed layout. On overflow, the contents of cells should clip from the left instead of the right. That is, if the width of the TD is less than the width of the text, the cell below should display "67890" instead of "12345".

This needs to work in IE7+ at minimum. Is there a way to do this in css without any JavaScript?

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed">
  <tr>
    <TD>
      12334567890
   </TD>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overflow to left instead of right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218065/overflow-to-left-instead-of-right)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could use:

```
direction:rtl;
```

Comment: I have to admit I thought of this, but his question was a bit confusing since he said the line below should be "67890" which is still reading left-to-right. Better wording on his part could help here.

Comment: This will work as long as you don't have punctuation in the cells. I think that text like "This is a sentence!" would look like "!This is a sentence".

Otherwise, this solution works.

Comment: adding direction:rtl to the TD did the job. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem like the most elegant solution for the actual need. I think either manipulating the data server side or client-side would be better so you can display X amount of characters at all times.

Answer (score 1):

I haven´t tried it, but you could try `text-align:right` or wrap the contents in a `div` and float that right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS3 property `word-wrap: break-word` but there's no way to control where it will break the word. It will fit whatever it can on the line and then break it down to the next, it won't keep the lines of equal length.

There is also the [`<wbr>`](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html) tag but I've never used or experimented with it, so I can't really tell you how to use it.