# overflow text to the left in a table WITHOUT rtl

Tags: html, css

I have a table that I am trying to make behave more-or-less like Excel. I've successfully made left-aligned cells overflow into cells to the right (by putting their contexts in a wrapper div with `max-width`, `overflow:visible`, and `white-space:nowrap`) but am having no success making right-aligned cells overflow to the left. I've tried floating the wrapper div to the right (and various permutations of that) without success; the text invariably overflows to the right regardless.

Other answers to this question on StackOverflow and elsewhere suggest using `dir:rtl`, but I really really don't want to do this. I don't know in advance which cells are going to overflow and I also don't want to deal with the wacky stuff it does to punctuation.

Bonus points if you can also figure out how to get a center-aligned cell to overflow equally into both neighbors.

edit: here is an example jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AlexGodofsky/2uaHN/2/

Comment: What browsers do you need to support? Can you post a fiddle? Did you try "display: inline-flex"?

Comment: What if you used `position: absolute; right: 0;`?

Comment: a fiddle or some code can help more to work on solution...

Comment: I'd prefer to support IE8, but even if you have a solution that only works in Chrome or FF I'd like to hear it. And I just added a fiddle.

Comment: I am experimenting with `position:absolute` now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found your Q&A while doing research for the same problem: getting text inside a table cell to align right and overflow to the left.

I strongly agree with you on *not* using `dir:rtl` as mentioned e.g. in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2994007/2286722). Besides the practical disadvantages with regards to puctuation: `dir` is *not* meant for this problem!

In [your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21465457/2286722), the height issue is caused by the absolute positioning of the inner div: it is placed outside the flow and thus takes no height.

I did get 'right align' to work using floats and I'm happy to share this minimal example here for anyone who may need it. I also have a 'bonus' solution for the center-case.

```css
td {
  width: 8em;
  max-width: 8em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
div.fix_right {
  float: right;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: right;
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: #ddd;
  /* and to obscure the contents of the cell on the left: */
  position: relative;
}
div.fix_center_a {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
div.fix_center_b {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* and to obscure the contents of the cell on the left: */
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>some text here</td>
    <td>
      <div class="fix_right">align right</div>
    </td>
    <td>some text here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>some text here</td>
    <td>
      <div class="fix_right">do align and overflow right</div>
    </td>
    <td>some text here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>some text here</td>
    <td>
      <div class="fix_center_a">
        <div class="fix_center_b">centered text, extending to the left and right</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>some text here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### Align to the right

I think the key in this solution is to use the combination of `float` in the `div` and `max-width` in the `td`.

The relative positioning and bg-color are needed in order to let the contents 'obscure' the contents of the column(s) to the left. If these left columns are empty anyway, this is not even needed.

### Center

This solution (unfortunately) needs an additional layer of non-semantic div, but it works as follows:

- The `td` is left alone so that it may get a border etc. Note that the border shows that the cell itself is not expanding, only the contents overflow it.
- The first `div` (`fix_center_a`) gets us in the middle of the cell and gets us the total width needed for the content.
- The second `div` (`fix_center_b`) just shifts the content 50% of the total width (from `fix_center_a`) to the left, thus centering the content.

(Because of the relative positioning of the first `div`, the content already obscures the content of the left and right cells if you apply a background-color on the `fix_center_b`.)

Comment: Switched the checkmark to you - your solution is much better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on crush's suggestion in the comments, I've figured out a way to do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/AlexGodofsky/2uaHN/3/

The key is for these cells to have an outer wrapper div with `position:relative` along with the normal wrapper styling (`max-width`, `overflow:visible`, and `white-space:nowrap`), then an inner wrapper div with a flexible size and `position:absolute` `right:0`.

An issue I ran into on the way is that you either need to give the outer wrapper a fixed height (`height:100%` does not work) or play with `vertical-align` on the `td`, otherwise the top of the outer wrapper will be in the middle of the cell. Which is optimal probably depends on whether you can know the row height in advance.