# Always show vertical ScrollBar in SlickGrid

Tags: slickgrid

I have a *SlickGrid* with a varying count of records in it. The application code will retrieve the data in "Chunks" of lets say 25 records each.

So i have my *SlickGrid* displayed with no records for a short time. Then the first 25 records arrive and are displayed -> no scrollbar is displayed, because there is enough space in the table.

Then the code retrieves the second set of 25 records and a scrollbar is needed and displayed.

Since everytime the table is sorted these requests are made, it can be very often. And the whole table is like jumping around because of the scrollbar appearing and disappearing every time.

Is there a way to force SlickGrid of displaying a scrollbar?

Answer (score 3):

through css

```
#myGrid .slick-viewport {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: @kavun is there a way to place the scrollbar on the left instead of the right?

Comment: @LeonardoTrimarchi `direction: rtl` is worth a shot https://stackoverflow.com/a/39874526/789893