# Show end of text when overflow in CSS

Tags: css, breadcrumbs

I have a breadcrumbs on my website (`|` symbolises the area I have for it):

```
| Home -> Some thing -> Some deeper thing                                            |
```

Currently, it has `overflow: hidden` set, so when it becomes too long, it results in:

```
| Home -> Some thing -> Some deeper thing -> Some page with very long and very import|
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to hide the beginning of the text instead of the end, so it should be:

```
| me thing -> Some deeper thing -> Some page with very long and very important title |
```

How to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overflow to left instead of right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218065/overflow-to-left-instead-of-right)

Comment: In the question @Bartdude linked to, the text is aligned to the right all the time. I want it to be aligned to the left if it fits the area what changes the problem drammatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with 2 `divs` and some simple javascript like this:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var inner = document.getElementById("inner").offsetWidth;
  var outer = document.getElementById("outer").offsetWidth;
  if(outer > inner)
    document.getElementById("inner").style.left = 0;
}
```

```css
#outer {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}
#inner {
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer"><div id="inner">Home -> Some thing -> Some deeper thing -> Some page with very long and very important title</div></div>
```

Comment: This always aligns text to the right, which is not desired in my case.

Comment: Take a look at my update. If you change the outer div to say 1000px, it will stay to the left.