# CSS: Float left & overflow left

Tags: jquery, html, css

This image should be self explanatory.

[image]

Basically, I'm trying to have a div behaving as follows:

- When there is enough space for the entire div to be displayed, the entire div will display, floating to the left.
- When there is not enough space, the div should overflow hidden to the left.

If CSS can't do this alone, do you have a link to similar working JS ?

JSFiddle that I'm trying to use to figure out: https://jsfiddle.net/375fmu1q/164/

```
<div class="outer-div">
    <div class="inner-div">
        <div class="part1">
            This is part 1 -
    </div>
        <div class="part2">
            This is part 2 -
    </div>
        <div class="part3">
            This is part 3 -
    </div>
        <div class="part4">
            This is part 4
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: set height or max-height property for inner-div

Comment: @ShrihariBalasubramani That works for not overflowing multiple lines, but doesn't help with end goal - overflowing left.

Comment: Have you ever heard about bootstrap?

Comment: @AEX you want it to come out of the whitebox and overflow to left?

Comment: @ZaraJamshaid Heard of it - haven't used it. Interested in anything that would work for this scenario. Pls link anything that fits the behavior.

Comment: @ShrihariBalasubramani I want it to have it overflow (hidden) to the left, like in the picture. So I want the right most part always visible and the left part to "slide".

Comment: @AEX Can we use `flexbox` ?

Comment: @Anuresh I don't know .. whatever works - If I knew I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: You've already got your answer, But I'll advise you to use bootstrap for your future work, It'll help you a lot, save your time and very easy to learn and use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one possible solution to your problem. This requires both CSS and JS to work. The outer and inner div should have the following understanding:

```
.outer-div {
    position: relative;
    // padding-top: <height of .inner-div>
}
.inner-div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

This will have the same effect as `float: left`. This is how the styles should work during normal size, i:e `.outer-div` width is greater than the `.inner-div` width. Now we are going to write a JS code that will detect if this condition has changed and apply the difference as negative left to achieve your desired effect.

```
const onResizeOrDetectChange = () => {
    const outerDiv = document.querySelector('.outer-div');
    const innerDiv = document.querySelector('.inner-div');
    const widthDiff = outerDiv.offsetWidth - innerDiv.offsetWidth

    // will be less than 0 when outer div width is less than inner div width
    if (widthDiff < 0) {
        innerDiv.style.left = widthDiff + 'px'
    } else {
        innerDiv.style.left = 0
    }
}
```

Call `onResizeOrDetectChange` when screen resize or any event where you would like to adjust and it can produce the desired effect you are looking for.

Here is the modified fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o7m7bo60/8/. I have used flex-box styling as compared to your `float: left` to make the `.inner-div` stay in one line

Answer (score 3):

One way you can do this by `direction:rtl` Refer : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218065/overflow-to-left-instead-of-right)

With **`Flexbox`** using `flex-flow: row-reverse;`

```css
body {margin:0;}
.outer-div {
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row-reverse;
  max-width: 400px;
}
.inner-div {
  display:flex;
}
.part {
  padding: 10px;
}
.part1 {
  background-color:red;
}
.part2 {
  background-color:blue;
}
.part3 {
  background-color:green;
}
.part4 {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-div">
  <div class="inner-div">     
    <div class="part part1">
    This is part 1 
    </div>  
    <div class="part part2">
    This is part 2 
    </div>  
    <div class="part part3">
     This is part 3 
    </div>  
    <div class="part part4">
    This is part 4 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Only reason I chose other approach as answer is because it was posted first.

Comment: This actually doesn't work :( ... if .outer-div { max-width: 600 } it will be obvious why ... it floats right, it doesn't float left.

Answer (score 0):

You can use display flex to solve this problem. See the code below. This will solve your problem.

```css
.outer-div {
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.inner-div {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.inner-div > div {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.part1 {
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  background-color:red;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.part2 {
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  background-color:blue;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.part3 {
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  background-color:green;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.part4 {
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  background-color:yellow;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-div">
  <div class="inner-div">     
    <div class="part1">
    This is part 1 -
    </div>  
    <div class="part2">
    This is part 2 -
    </div>  
    <div class="part3">
     This is part 3 -
    </div>  
    <div class="part4">
    This is part 4 
    </div> 
    <div class="part1">
    This is part 1 -
    </div>  
    <div class="part2">
    This is part 2 -
    </div>  
    <div class="part3">
     This is part 3 -
    </div>  
    <div class="part4">
    This is part 4 
    </div> 
    <div class="part1">
    This is part 1 -
    </div>  
    <div class="part2">
    This is part 2 -
    </div>  
    <div class="part3">
     This is part 3 -
    </div>  
    <div class="part4">
    This is part 4 
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```