# Overflow elements to left instead of right, but for elements

Tags: html, css, overflow

When you apply `overflow-x: hidden`,

> it'll scroll you all the way to the **LEFT** and hide everything that overflows to the **RIGHT**,

like: (and of course it also hides the scrollbar, which I didn't do here.)
[image]

I want the opposite behavior:

> it'll scroll you all the way to the **RIGHT** and hide everything that overflows to the **LEFT**,

so it'll look like: (again the scrollbar shouldn't be visible of course)

[image]

---

Also, when the `overflow` isn't triggered the natural "flow" shouldn't be affected. The items should still start from the left like so:

[image]

---

Here is the reference code:

```css
nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: stretch;

    justify-content: flex-start !important;

    overflow-x: shown;

    ol {
        flex: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <body>
    <nav>
<ol>
  <li class="dir marked">
    <a href="../../..">
      LinearAlgebra
    </a>
  </li>
</ol>
<ol>
  <li class="dir marked">
    <a href="../..">
      other
    </a>
  </li>
</ol>
<ol>
  <li class="dir marked">
    <a href="..">
      nested
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="file">
    <a href="../../test.html">
      test
    </a>
  </li>
</ol>
<ol>
  <li class="dir marked">
    <a href="">
      x2Nested
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="file">
    <a href="../nested.html">
      nested
    </a>
  </li>
</ol>
<ol>
  <li class="file">
    <a href="anotherFile.html">
      anotherFile
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="file">
    <a href="x2Nested.html">
      x2Nested
    </a>
  </li>
</ol>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Note we are dealing with `<ol>` elements, not text, so `direction: rtl` won't work. Hence why this question is different from: [Overflow to left instead of right](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218065/7123519)

Comment: I don't get it :D can you explain a little more what you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility using a wrapper, and positioning the nav to the right:

Edited: added min-width

```css
#container {
    width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: solid 1px green;
    height: 100px;
}

#container:hover {
    width: 800px;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: stretch;

    justify-content: flex-start !important;

  right: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  width: fit-content;
  border: solid 1px red;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<nav>
<ol>
  <li class="dir marked">
    <a href="../../..">
      LinearAlgebra
    </a>
  </li>
</ol>
<ol>
  <li class="dir marked">
    <a href="../..">
      other
    </a>
  </li>
</ol>
<ol>
  <li class="dir marked">
    <a href="..">
      nested
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="file">
    <a href="../../test.html">
      test
    </a>
  </li>
</ol>
<ol>
  <li class="dir marked">
    <a href="">
      x2Nested
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="file">
    <a href="../nested.html">
      nested
    </a>
  </li>
</ol>
<ol>
  <li class="file">
    <a href="anotherFile.html">
      anotherFile
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="file">
    <a href="x2Nested.html">
      x2Nested
    </a>
  </li>
</ol>
    </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is good, however it creates a new problem. Now whenever `overflow` isn't triggered, [my items are aligned to the right](https://i.gyazo.com/d8c6534d0815c38e84f6c0567edd6d0c.png), but [they should be aligned to the left](https://i.gyazo.com/4321330ced0befc872d85fed9ae6abeb.png)! Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: I have edited the code. Hover the element to see it in action.